# Running a VM fail

Tags: installation, vmware, logging

I can't boot to my OS because VMware likes to hate me now and this is what I got

```
VMware Workstation unrecoverable error: (vcpu-0)
vcpu-0:VERIFY vmcore/vmm/main/physMem_monitor.c:1180
A log file is available in "C:\Users\waton\Documents\Virtual Machines\OS X 10.8\vmware.log".  
You can request support.
To collect data to submit to VMware support, choose "Collect Support Data" from the Help menu.
You can also run the "vm-support" script in the Workstation folder directly.
We will respond on the basis of your support entitlement.
```

I was trying to install Mac OS X to my external hdd but its not about the install its just the boot up error that I can't get rid of

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the log file?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Here you go! https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ahgh_PHgiTX1viUzCCO_0JRHBHzi

Comment: @JohnnyVegas the thing I'm trying to do is to install Niresh on external HDD and boot with my host and then get all of the stuff but the hardest part is the drivers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: @Tetsujin idk wheres the off topic on here? does that mean I have to delete it or I get banned?

Comment: It's off topic because the community decided it ought to be. Your version of OS X is not licensed, because it isn't running on Apple hardware. Did you read my linked meta post? There ought to be no ban involved - you need to do something wrong rather than mistaken for that to happen.

Comment: @Tetsujin also Remix OS question will be coming up so I hope that's not off topic

Comment: I've no idea about Remix

Comment: @Tetsujin Lol, I think its posted http://superuser.com/q/1131074/647712

Comment: Questions about running OS X on non-Apple hardware ("Hackintosh") are off-topic because of the questionable legality of doing so. See [Are "Hackintosh" questions allowed?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471)